# How to open and edit .CNDF Satellite Channel File

Tags: file-format

After hours on Google I cant find any good reference info on the .CNDF file format for Satellite channel lists stored on Sat box's.

I do know that there is .NDF (uncompressed) & .CNDF (Compressed) versions of the file format.

I basically want to open & un-compress the .CNDF file in my C# app, play around with it, then compress and save it out again.

Any pointers to the file format data sheet or any decent examples, especially the compression method used. Thanks